# Полное или неполное предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

**В первый раз мачеха подходит к Гортензии, потом к Жавотте.**

Вторая часть предложения является неполной? Нужно ли тире после "потом"?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что у вас написано правильно: тире ставится в зависимости от значения слова "потом". Согласно [1](https://sci.house/russkiy-yazyik-scibook/osnovnyie-printsipyi-punktuatsii-36255.html),

> В предложении *Жених был приветлив и очень важен, потом — он был
>   неглуп и очень зажиточен* (М. Горький) тире указывает на то, что слово
>   потом имеет здесь значение «кроме того». При отсутствии тире потом
>   имело бы значение «после чего-либо», «впоследствии», не­уместное в
>   данном случае.

Ещё один пример из литературы (Жюль Верн, "*Путешествие к центру Земли*"), подтверждающий правило:

> И спокойно, флегматически он приложился сначала к щеке хозяина, потом
>   к щеке хозяйки, потом к щекам всех девятнадцати детей.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поставила здесь тире: **В первый раз мачеха подходит к Гортензии, потом ―  к Жавотте.**

Во второй части предложения пропущено несколько членов, поэтому пропуск лучше обозначить паузой.

Answer (score 0):

Гораздо легче было бы рассуждать, если бы было просто "Mачеха подходит к Гортензии, потом к Жавотте", но тут добавлено "в первый раз", что делает предложение "трудно усвояемым".

Возможно, она подходит к Гортензии, потом к Жавотте — и все это в первый раз? Или в первый раз она подходит к Гортензии, а во второй - к Жавотте? В первый раз к Гортензии, а все остальные разы — к Жавотте?

Наиболее вероятным кажется мне такой контекст.

**В первый раз мачеха подходит к Гортензии, потом к Жавотте, во второй раз — сначала к Жавотте, а потом к Гортензии.**

При таком построении предложения тире после слова *потом* ставить не нужно. На мой взгляд, в таком предложении *к Гортензии, к Жавотте* — однородные члены.

Если же имеется в виду, что в первый раз она подходит к Гортензии, а во второй  к Жавотте (или первый раз к Гортензии, а все последующие разы — к Жавотте), то следовало бы выразить это как-то по-другому, например так.

**В первый раз мачеха подходит к Гортензии, во второй раз — к Жавотте.**
**В первый раз мачеха подходит к Гортензии, а потом — только к Жавотте.**